# WinPhone7 programming ListBox Multi Column

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, listbox

I have a listbox  which shows video title and thumbnails in WinPhone 7 programming.
I linked listbox to it's ItemsSource.

```
listbox1.ItemsSource = videos;
```

In the xaml:

```
<Listbox.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding title}"/>
      <Image Source="{Binding thumbnail}"/>
    </StackPanel>
  </DataTemplate>
</Listbox.ItemTemplate>
```

Now my listbox has only one column which has title text and thumbnail image in each row.
But what I want to is a listbox with 2 columns, each column has title text and thumbnail image in each row.

Listbox

```
---------------------------
| title1     |  title2    |
| thumb1     |  thumb2    |
----------------------------
| title3     |  title4    |
| thumb3     |  thumb4    |
...
```

I've spent a lot of time trying to find solution, but I cannot find it.
I hope stack overflow guys will solve this for me.
Any idea is welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
       <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <toolkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
      <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <StackPanel Orientation = "Horizontal">
                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding title}"/>
                 <Image Source="{Binding Thumbnail}"/>
               <StackPanel/>
            </DataTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: thanks nucleons, but my listbox has 2columns and several rows. 
(row 1, col 1) title1, thumb1 (row1, col2) title2, thumb2 (row2, col1) title3, thumb3 (row2, col2) title4, thumb4 ....
Could you know me how can I link itemsSource to the listbox?

Comment: Nucleons just made that for you, the wrap panel will put your third item in the second row if the sizes are good. For example if your listbox is 480 wide and your items are 240 wide.

Comment: Set ItemWidth="" and ItemHeight="" in wrappanel.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, it seems to me you can just set the orientation of your `StackPanel` to Horizontal

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
```

Is that what you're looking for? If not please elaborate.

EDIT: Using a WrapPanel as ItemsPanel.

This example uses the `WrapPanel` from the [Silverlight for Windows Phone Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/71550).
You may need to download and install this, or include a namespace definition for things to work!

Also note that the `WrapPanel` will wrap as much items as will fit per row. So if you only want exactly two items on a row, you may have to tweak the width of the `ListBox`.

```
<PhoneApplicationPage 
    ....
    xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit" 
....
>

<!-- More Stuff -->

<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
           <toolkit:WrapPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
   <Listbox.ItemTemplate>
          <!-- your template -->
   </Listbox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>

<!-- More Stuff -->
```

Comment: my listbox has 2 columns and several rows.
each cell should has title and thumb, and they should be consecutive.

Comment: @ttotto: Can you include a better visual of what's wrong now, and how it should look?

Comment: ----------------
title1 | title2
thumb1 | thumb2
----------------
title3 | title4
thumb3 | thumb4
----------------
...

Comment: (row 1, col 1) title1, thumb1 (row1, col2) title2, thumb2                  
(row2, col1) title3, thumb3  (row2, col2) title4, thumb4 ....

Comment: So you want two items to appear in one row, correct?
In that case you might want to use a WrapPanel as your ItemsPanelTemplate.

Comment: Thanks again. yes, i want two items to appear in one row and they are from the one items source. could you know me how can I link items source for this using WrapPanel?